# Как сделать полностью прозрачное окно с непрозрачной рамкой?

Tags: java, javafx, swing, java-8

Мне нужен полный доступ к прозрачной части, т.е. чтобы там можно было нажимать мышкой и т.п. (как будто бы прозрачного окна и нет и оно не перекрывало доступ к видимой части экрана) С помощью какой технологии это можно сделать в Java? Прямо на экране рисовать рамку просто с помощью Graphics? Покажите пример кода.

Comment: Если не секрет, зачем вам такое окно? Может использовать какой-нибудь другой подход?

Comment: Ну мне нужно делать скриншоты определённой области экрана, причем выделить эту область рамкой и при необходимости обеспечить туда беспрепятственный доступ для действий пользователя. Рамку и окно наверно можно полностью убирать при попадании мыши в диапазон рамки, а при выходе мышки из диапазона снова показывать рамку и окно. Мне главное понять в какую сторону то вообще двигаться, какие способы есть?

Comment: у javaFx есть свойство на контролы клик мышкой сквозь, а что бы реализовать прозрачное окно, нужно для stage применять стиль transparent или undecorated (не помню какой). И еще какую-то штуку, тогда java производит сделать прозрачное окно. Кода в наличии нет. Вероятно потребуется реализовывать перемещение окна и изменение размеров самостоятельно.

Comment: для swing посмотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20808503/5661663)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем не надо было ничего усложнять, в моём случае для выделения области просто рисуем рамку и считаем что это "окно".

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Window w = new Window(null) {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.orange);
                g.drawRect(1400, 200, 50, 200);
            }

            @Override
            public void update(Graphics g) {
                paint(g);
            }
        };
        w.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        w.setBounds(w.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
        w.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
        w.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: А теперь попробуйте в винде вывести это окно, переключиться на другое приложение, а потом вывести снова. Второй раз поверх всех окон оно не появится. Джава - плохой вариант для таких целей

Comment: Да нормально всё, рамка как висела так и висит после переключения на другое  приложение.

Comment: не, там все сложно. Я пробовал делать окно поверх всех на javaFX. Там трабл начинается, когда меняешь фокус на другое приложение. То есть, если открыть окно поверх всех, а потом закрыть его программно, то все остается нормально и в следующий раз все сработает. Но если вывести окно поверх и сменить фокус на другое приложение, а после этого скрыть, то в следующий раз окно не покажется поверх всех, а будет только мигать в тулбаре сообщая, что прилоежние желает что-то вывести. Из вариантов я думал сделать полностью прозрачное окно и рамку, чтобы фокус нельзя было потерять хотя бы мышью

Comment: @Serhii Dikobrazko я не на javaFX

Comment: а. Ну может так. Но рекомендую все же попробовать с фокусом потестить, чтобы под конец не напороться. Это ограничения безопасности именно винды. На той же убунту таких проблем не возникет

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте  Robot#createScreenCapture().

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: Думаю, человек знает как скриншоты делать. Вопрос не в этом

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, Вы считаете, что автор изобретает свой Lightshot Skillbrains'ов?